# Using Python to Decode Steganography Images (example images at Wikipedia)

Tags: python, image, image-processing, steganography

At [Wikipedia's Steganography Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography#Digital_messages) there is an example image given with hidden image data.

- [Original Image of trees found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Steganography_original.png)
- [Decrypted image data of a cat found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Steganography_recovered.png)

Wikipedia notes:

> [Image of a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Steganography_original.png) with a steganographically hidden image. The hidden image is revealed by removing all but the two least significant bits of each color component and a subsequent normalization. The hidden image is shown [(here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Steganography_recovered.png).

**QUESTION:** I'm confused about "subsequent normalisation"; assuming working Python 2.x code based on PIL module, how does normalisation factor into the retrieval?

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: *Given the above information, how would Python code go about decoding the cat image from the tree image?* -- Should I rephrase?

Comment: That's not a question, this is a QA site, not a "write-my-code-for-me" service.

Comment: I know how SE works mate. Have you got anything more productive to add other than this? I'm not asking anyone to write code for me.

Comment: "The hidden image is revealed by removing all but the two least significant bits of each color component and a subsequent normalization." If you don't want code, that's all you need to decode the image, is anything not clear enough?

Comment: I understand you get people coming here who've done nothing and expect the world, but I'm not one of them. I'll add my code as soon as I'm not using iOS, but would someone please clarify the "subsequent normalisation" part?

Comment: "clarify the "subsequent normalisation" part" Now that is a question. If you put that in the question, this would have been fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subsequent normalization is [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) of each color component.

Say, the the red color component of pixel 1,1 is 234.

The binary representation of 234 is

```
In [1]: bin(234)
Out[1]: '0b11101010'
```

We can remove everything but the two least significant bits with some bitwise operation:

```
In [2]: bin(234 & 0b11)
Out[2]: '0b10'
```

The range of a 8-bit image is 8-bits or 256 possible shades. But the range of our color value is just 2-bits or 4 possible shades.

The normalization part is doing [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) to stretch the 2-bit value to fill 8-bit space:

```
In [3]: (234 & 0b11) * (256/4)
Out[2]: 128
```

Do this is done on each color component and the cat would appear.

Comment: The correct conversion factor is 255/3. If you multiply the values in the range [0,3] by 256/4 = 64, you get values in the range [0,192].

Answer (score 2):

Normalization is the process of changing a range of values into another range of values.

You have the range [0,3] because of the binary values of 00, 01, 10 and 11. The reason why you want to normalize this to [0,255] is to cover the whole range of pixel intensities. If you were to just save an image from an array with values in the range [0,3], it would appear black because all of these values are very close to 0 and very far away from 255.

The wikipedia page on [image normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing)) gives you the general formula for this. It also shows an example of converting the range [50,180] (call this range A) to [0,255] (range B).

First, we shift A so it starts from zero. Effectively, you subtract the lowest value (50) so that [50,180] becomes [0,130] (call this C). The maximum distance for C is 130-0 = 130 and for B it is 255-0 = 255. So you'll need to multiply all values of C by 255/130. Since the lowest value in C is 0, so it will be for C * 255/130. But if B doesn't start from 0, you simply add the necessary offset to account for this.

In case words are confusing, here's a visualisation of converting [2,5] to [-4,4].

[image: Range normalization demonstration]

In your cases, the normalization is from [0,3] to [0,255]. Since both ranges start from 0, you don't need any offsets, just a simple multiplication by 255/3. This result converts {0,1,2,3} to {0,85,170,255}.

A bit of caution here, 255/3 is conveniently an integer number. But if you were normalizing, say [0,7], the most accurate conversion would require the float scaling factor 255/7. Whether you keep that as a float or round it to an integer is outside the scope of this answer.

The simplest code to achieve this would be

```
import Image
import numpy as np

# The array will be of type `np.uint8`. For integer computations that exceed
# this range, use `np.asarray(Image.open(...), dtype=int)`.
stego = np.asarray(Image.open('Steganography_original.png'))
extracted = stego & 0b00000011
extracted *= (255 / 3)

# Compare result with the one from wikipedia
wiki_extracted = np.asarray(Image.open('Steganography_recovered.png').convert('RGB'))
if np.all(wiki_extracted == extracted):
    print 'All pixels match'
```

Comment: *Whether you keep that as a float or round it to an integer is outside the scope of this answer.* : could you recommend a source on this subject which I can follow up?

Comment: If 255/7 = 36, then {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} -> {0,36,72,108,144,180,216,252}. If 255/7 = 36.4285..., you first normalize the range [0,7] and then round the values to integers, then {0,36,72,109,145,182,218,255}. I would choose the latter because of the former's cumulative precision error. If you were working with an image format where the pixel intensities are stored as floats, you'd also want the scaling factor to be a float.