# python 3.4 steganography (image encryption)

Tags: python, steganography

ive been trying to find a way to encrypt images into other image files, for example just look at the below link

[Using Python to Decode Steganography Images (example images at Wikipedia)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121436/using-python-to-decode-steganography-images-example-images-at-wikipedia)

now this would work just fine, but I have python 3.4 and the PIL module and others just wont work properly, does anyone have any suggestion on how to fix this or another method to encrypt the images

Comment: Some of the syntax and modules have changed from Python 2.x to 3.x and you'd have to manually change that. What errors do you get? What and how does something not *work*? What have you tried? Have you looked into Pillow?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Pillow](https://python-pillow.github.io/) the python3 fork ?

Comment: can you tell me how to install it into python

Comment: Check the read the docs link it should have everything you need to know

Comment: @MeelakNishom: To install  a Python package, use `pip`  e.g.: `pip install Pillow` or if you haven't added Python's `Scripts` folder to `%PATH%` envvar on Windows then `py -m pip install Pillow`